# How to Extract Date from between two underscores in Filename by Formula in Excel?

Tags: excel-2016

I need to extract the date from the middle of Excel filenames by formula. Length of text before and after underscores may vary so I am trying to do it based on the underscores.  E.g. filenames:

XXX123_20190122_XXXABC

XX123_20190121_XXXABCD

XXXX123_20190120_XXXABC

I can do it in two different formulae:

This gets the filename:

=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1,FIND(".",CELL("filename",A1))-1-FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1)))

and this takes the date from that cell:

=MID(A9, FIND("*", A9, 1)+1,  FIND("*", A9, FIND("*", A9, 1)+1) - FIND("*", A9, 1) -1 )

But I need to do it in one forumla and I have not been able to combine them yet.  Does anyone know how to do it? 
Thank you,

Comment: What is your expected output?  Why don't you just concatenate together the two formulas?

Comment: I need the date in one column. ok I will try to concatenate the two formulae.

Comment: No Concatenate does not work, it returns the full filename plus the date, I need the date only.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it, hopefully this will save someone that time and effort.  Perhaps there is a more elegant solution but this works if it has to be a formula:

=MID(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,FIND(".",CELL("filename",$A$1))-1-FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))), FIND("*", MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,FIND(".",CELL("filename",$A$1))-1-FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))), 1)+1,  FIND("*", MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,FIND(".",CELL("filename",$A$1))-1-FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))), FIND("*", MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,FIND(".",CELL("filename",$A$1))-1-FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))), 1)+1) - FIND("*", MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,FIND(".",CELL("filename",$A$1))-1-FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))), 1) -1 )